# Crystal Report - Suppress fields in text object

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I've put four fields inside a text object. Is it possible to suppress the fields inside a text object? (CR2008)

Example:

Field1 - Eng Name - Peter Lee

Field2 - Birth - 20/5

Field3 - Age - M

Field4 - Comma ( , )

I've put those fields inside a text object like this:

{Field1}{Field4}{Field2}{Field4}{Field3}

Result: Peter Lee , 20/5 , M

Now I want to suppress last two fields {Field4}{Field3} if {Field3} is null

Result: Peter Lee , 20/5

As the suppress function of field in text object was disappeared. How can I do this?

---

Modified on 29 Oct

Actually my cases are more complicated. I've total 5 fields. (Get data from Stored Procedures)

{Collection Date} {Payment Method} {Bank Name} {Cheque No} {Balance}

Every fields can be NULL or with value

I try to modify SP like this:

CASE

WHEN {Collection Date} <> NULL THEN

{Collection Date} + ', '

ELSE ''

END AS 'CollectDate'

CASE

WHEN {Payment Method} <> NULL THEN

{Payment Method} + ', '

ELSE ''

END AS 'PayMethod'

etc....

If {Payment Method} {Bank Name} {Cheque No} {Balance} both are NULL then I will get the result:

15/10, (with Comma at the end)

Is there any simply method to do this? Otherwise I need to add many conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a formula field, and from there you check if field4 id null

something like this

```
Local StringVar y;
y := {Field1} + " " + {Field2};
if isnull({Field4}) = false then
  y := y + {Field3} + " " + {Field4};
```

Then you assign your formula field to the text object

Answer (score 0):

Hi In the suppress condition of field 4 write this.
isnull(field 3)

Comment: Because all fields are inside a text object. I cannot see the suppress function when I format the field.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a formula field to get the desired result.

if isnull({field3}) then
     {Field1}&{Field4}&" "&{Field2}
else
     {Field1}&{Field4}&" "&{Field2}&{Field4}&" "&{Field3}

Then use the formula field in the Text Object.